# How to get constraints back after shutting off autolayout?

Tags: autolayout

I am relatively new to coding on Swift and Xcode. When I was attempting to fix the design of my app, I unchecked the "Use Auto Layout" button assuming that it would simply shut off auto layout for that specific entity (An MKMapView in this situation):

[image]

Unfortunately, this removed all the constraints that I had for the entire app! I quickly tried to revert my changes by rechecking the box but it did not return to normal. Are all my constraints gone forever or is there a way to recover them?

Unfortunately, my repository is slightly out of date and I would lose a lot of work if I were to reset with the most current version saved. Any help would be amazing and really end the extreme amount of stress I just placed on myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, your constraints are probably gone. Unchecking this box removes all constraints.

If you did not close and open your project since unchecking the box, you can try and undo the change, it **will** revert to the previous state if the conditions are ideal.

Comment: Thank you. Not the news that I wanted to hear but you saved me a lot of time researching.